# Why does my code give me a single value rather than a list

Tags: python, list, csv, indexing

I have been working with some CSV files, i am a beginner but i feel i am getting a hang of it, though i can not figure out why when i try to print out the second column in my csv file, python prints out a single value rather than a list of all the values in the second column (they would all be 2018-01 since that column is the same throughout the table).

I was under the impression my code split the columns into individual lists per row therefore if i wanted to print `sep[1]`, i would have got the value of the 2nd column for each row. Though currently `sep[1]` gives me a single value.

Here is my code

```
with open('2018-01-btp-street.csv', 'r') as file:
    for row in file:
        sep = row.split(',')


print (sep[1])!
```

Here is an image of the csv file https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijB1e.jpg

Comment: what is `!` for?

Comment: It was a typo sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting `sep` every time you loop over a new row. Let's say the file has 2 rows:

```
with open('2018-01-btp-street.csv', 'r') as file:
    for row in file:  # first loop: 
        sep = row.split(',')  # sep now contains all items in the first row that were separated by commas.
    #second loop: sep now only(!) contains all items in the SECOND row that were separated by commas.
```

you can test this by adding `print(sep)` right after the definition of `sep` inside the loop.

Now, what you want is the second column in each row. [`string.split(other_string)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)returns a list of all individual pieces of a string that were separated by `other_string`. So you can store every one of these lists in a new list, like this:

```
all_values = []
with open('2018-01-btp-street.csv', 'r') as file:
    for row in file:
        sep = row.split(',')
        all_values.append(sep)  # this is the important part. sep will still be reset every loop, but the values are now stored in all_values.
```

now, you have a list of lists. To get the second value of all every list, do

```
for l in all_values:
    print(l[1])
```

You can also use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that does the same thing:

```
with open('2018-01-btp-street.csv', 'r') as file:
     all_values = [row.split(',') for row in file]
```

`all_values` looks like this:

```
[[row1_col1, row1_col2, row1_col3, ...], [row2_col1, row2_col2, row2_col3,...], ...]
```

Or, to get lists of all columns instead:

```
with open('2018-01-btp-street.csv', 'r') as file:
     all_values = [row.split(',') for row in file]
all_columns = [[l[i] for l in all_values] for i in range(len(all_values[0]))]
```

which will give you a list that looks like

```
[[row1_col1, row2_col1, row3_col1], [row1_col2, row2_col2, row3_col2], ...]
```

and now you can use

```
print(all_columns[1])
```

to get all values of the second column.

Comment: Great answer, so just to make sure i have understood this correctly, the reason why print sep[1] only friends part of the list rather than the list of the list i expected is because row.split makes one list of all the string used in my file seperated by a comma for each individual element in the list?

And because i have used sep in the for loop, it ends up iterating thus combing each of the values in each row all into one list?

Comment: Kind of. You iterate over all rows in the file. Using `split` in every loop returns a list of all individual pieces of this row, separated at all places where there was a comma. You define `sep` to be a copy of this list, but you **redefine** it again for every row, in every  iteration of the for loop. So in the end, `sep` is basically the same as `last_row.split (',')`, and **only** the last row. So it's a list of strings, therefore `sep[1]` is just a single string.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `file` is a "file-like" object. Iterating through it gives you strings at each iteration so `row` is a string.

Calling `row.split()` returns a list. So `sep` is a list of strings. So `sep[1]` should indeed be a string.

Python libraries like `csv` and `pandas` have abstractions for columns and working with columns, but in this case you're not going to have that.

`!` at the end of your code sample doesn't look correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

You indicated that you want to "list of all the values in the second column".  In that case you need to do the `print()` inside the loop...so you need to indent the function call so that it is inside the loop.

```
with open('2018-01-btp-street.csv', 'r') as file:
    for row in file:
        sep = row.split(',')
        print (sep[1])
```

Your initial code runs through the loop and then does the `print()` of the last value after the loop has finished.